# Detecting file download through http request

Tags: file, http, networking, browser

I'm trying to filter in my proxy server whenever the client asks for download file from webserver or it just element in the page (e.g picture in the site).

Now I'm little confused about how it done in http request and response.

From what I understood, the client asks for URI (e.g `http://www.example.com/directory/file.zip`) and the server responses with `200 OK` and with the file and headers [ `Content-Length: 30025, Content-Type: application/zip Accept-Ranges: bytes` and more...]

How can I know if the client asks for download the file or it just needed to be on the website page on the browser?
or it maybe the browser decision?

Comment: What are you actually trying to determine? Is there a reason you need to know "why" they are requesting a particular URL? That may help better with getting an answer for you.

Comment: I would like to analyze every downloadable file that the client downloads for security reasons, I search for the pattern to get only the file download request (actually the answers) and not the other requests and responses that used to show on the website.

Comment: There's no fundamental difference between stuff being "downloaded" versus requested as part of a page. The closest thing is when the Content-Disposition header is "attachment", that would be for items that are in a sort of "save as" mode. But a person could simply request any part of the page manually as a save as. If security is a concern, *every* piece of content should be scanned.

Comment: I run different scan on files that downloaded by the user than the other items in the webpage, what I actually mean is what is the pattern to filter the specific download files (what you mean by saying "save as" mode)
I know about Content-Disposition but it not shows all the times that the user has the option to "save as"

Comment: I can't think of any pattern it would have, most likely the Referer would be the same as for items on the page

Comment: I find a way but its working 80% of the cases. You should ask if the "Content-Disposition" is in the headers of the responses, if yes its a download file, or if the header "Content-Type" has value that the browser cannot show like "exe" or "mp3".
Now the problem is how I know what the browser can show and what now ? I have serval Content-Type values like "exe,mp3,ppt,xls..." NOTE. I use Iceweasel

Answer (score 0):

You cannot able to find it very simple.

Because every website using their own way of techniques. You need to do for individual website.

Check the Request.Method = "POST"

As far we detected few websites

Samples below :

// Dropbox uses chunks of octet-stream requests:

```
if (url.ToLower().Contains("/chunked_upload?") && url.Contains("chunk=0"))
{
   //File Upload through this URL       
}
```

// Yahoo uses savewithattachment method

```
if (url.ToLower().Contains("savewithattachment"))
{
//File Upload through this URL  
}
```

// Office365 Uses

```
if (url.ToLower().Contains("createattachment"))
{
//File Upload through this URL  
}
```

//Google use

```
 if (Header.Contains("content-disposition") && (value.Contains("attachment") || Header.Contains("form-data") || value.Contains("name")))
 {
 //File Upload through this URL 
 }
```